# Extract users from two Active Directory groups

Tags: active-directory, jira, bamboo, bitbucket-server, ldap-query

I have tried multiple times to get this to work, but I haven't figured it out yet, so I'm asking in here, hoping that someone will be able to help me out.

I am using Atlassian's Bitbucket, Jira and Bamboo and they're all synced with an AD. At the moment I am using my AD user to retrieve all the other users. It works, but it's not optimal, as the password expires every three months, and I have to change the LDAP user login info on all three applications. We have ordered a Service User, where the password doesn't expire, but the problem is that the Service User is in another group.

The picture below shows how the AD is set up. My Service User is in a group called Special Users. I would like to use this user as the login user in the settings. This way I would never have to think about changing password, when my AD password expires.

[image: AD setup]

I would then like to retrieve all the users from the "Normal Users" group.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: An OU is not a group. Create a new security group, add all the users to it, and then set the Group Object Filter setting in {BitBucket,Jira,Bamboo} to `(&(objectClass=group)(cn=group_name))`

Comment: Jira has an internal Crowd out of the box, you may let Jira connect to User directory and let all other application use Jira for authorization. This would save time by only updating your LDAP password every 3 months on 1 application and reflected on all 3 applications

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen. I work at a company where I dont have the rights to create new groups. This is the setup at my company. Is there any chance to extract one user from a OU and all users from another OU?

Comment: Only if you target a common ancestor OU - which, in lieu of group memberships you can filter against, will also include any other users from the first OU. So no, go tell the AD admin at your company that you need a security group for this assigment :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also add multiple user directories pointing to different parts of your Active Directory.

Jira has an internal Crowd out of the box.

You may let Jira connect to User directory and let all other application use Jira for authintication.

This would save time by only updating your LDAP password every 3 months on 1 application and reflected on all 3 applications

Comment: That would save me some time, but wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't it fix the problem? If you have two user directories pointing to different parts of you active directory, Both directories would be available in your User list.

Comment: Because i'd still have to change my password every 3 months.